# Unable to merge dex multiDexEnabled true also not work

Tags: android, android-studio, native

Please Help Me

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

I try to Clean & Rebuild The Project But It still
I Delete .gradle Folder But Nothing Happend

this my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ekaldroid.chat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.7.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

    //Firebase & Google
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

    //test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I try

> multiDexEnabled true

but not working anymore

full Source here https://github.com/ElclarkKuhu/EDchat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'
```

OR THIS

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
```

Each version of `FirebaseUI` has dependency on a fixed version of these libraries,

```
FirebaseUI Version  Firebase/Play Services Version
3.2.2               11.8.0
3.1.3               11.8.0
3.1.2               11.6.2
3.1.0               11.4.2
3.0.0               11.4.2
2.4.0               11.4.0
2.3.0               11.0.4
2.2.0               11.0.4
2.1.1               11.0.2
2.0.1               11.0.1
1.2.0               10.2.0
1.1.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.1               10.0.0 or 10.0.1
1.0.0               9.8.0
```

for more information [FirebaseUI-Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android)

Comment: Thanks. I Change The Firebase ui to 3.2.2 And Its work fine